# Line that minimizes square distance to set of 3D points?

Tags: geometry, statistics

Given a set of $n$ points in euclidean $\mathbb{R}^3$, $(x_1, y_1, z_1), (x_2, y_2, z_2), ...,(x_n, y_n, z_n)$, how can I calculate a line (defined, say, parametrically by some point $L = (L_x, L_y, L_z)$ and some unit vector direction $D = (D_x, D_y, D_z)$ where for each $d \in \mathbb{R}$ there is a point on the line $L +dD$) that minimizes the mean of the shortest square distance from each point to some point on the line?

That is, L and D such that the following is minimized:

$$ \sum_{i}argmin_{d \in \mathbb{R}}|L+dD - (x_i, y_i, z_i)|^2 $$

It looks kind of like an ordinary least squares regression, but not really, right?

Comment: You might prefer to minimize the mean square distance rather than the mean distance.

Comment: Due to the absolute value, you probably will have to resort to numerical methods. Starting point "IRLS".

Comment: Minimizing square distance is fine if there is direct solution.

Comment: Updated to square distance.